# Validation for multi-step form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup, mantine

I am trying to make a multi-step form using that checks if the first two input fields are valid before moving on the the next step. The code below validates the two fields, but continues to the next step regardless if the forms are valid or not. I suspect the problem lies in the fact the onClick hook is changing the state without any checks. I do not know how to check if the fields are valid or not, before changing the state. I am using yup for validation alongside mantine for a component library.

```js
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup.string().email('Email is invalid.').required(),
  password: yup.string().required(),
});

function Example() {
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(0);
  const form = useForm({
    schema: yupResolver(schema),
    initialValues: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      firstName: "",
      lastName: ""
    }
  });

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={form.onSubmit((values) => {
        console.log(values);
      })}
    >
      <Paper shadow="xs" p="md">
        {activeStep === 0 && (
          <>
            <Title>Info</Title>
            <Group>
              <TextInput
                label="Email"
                {...form.getInputProps("email")}
              />
              <TextInput
                label="Password"
                {...form.getInputProps("password")}
              />
            </Group>
          </>
        )}

        {activeStep === 1 && (
          <>
            {" "}
            <Title>Personal</Title>
            <Group>
              <TextInput
                label="First name"
                {...form.getInputProps("firstName")}
              />
              <TextInput
                label="Last names"
                {...form.getInputProps("lastName")}
              />
            </Group>
          </>
        )}

        <Group mt="xl">
          <Button
            onClick={() => setActiveStep((prev) => prev - 1)}
            disabled={activeStep === 0}
          >
            Previous
          </Button>
          <Button
            onClick={() => setActiveStep((prev) => prev + 1)}
            type="submit"
            disabled={activeStep === 1}
          >
            Next
          </Button>
        </Group>
      </Paper>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: Try formik-wizard-form

Comment: ive tried but it doesn't seem to work, the form just moves to the next step without validation.